# Use objects from a 3rd party library as models in Django Rest Framework development

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I tried to describe it best I could in the title, but basically, I want to write an API using the Django REST Framework, but instead of using the Django db and pre defining models, I want my API to take an HTTP call from the user, use that to call another libraries functions, take the objects the 3rd party lib returns, build models based on what it gets back, serialize to JSON and give it back to the caller in JSON.

right now I'm using an extremeley simple class adn function to test this concept. it's got an object definition and a function that reads from a text file and converts it into an object list:

```
class myObj:
    id = None
    port = None
    cust = None
    product = None

    def __init__(self, textLine):
        props = [x.strip() for x in textLine.split(',')]
        self.id = props[0]
        self.port = props[1]
        self.cust = props[2]
        self.product = props[3]

def getObjList():
    lines = [line.strip() for line in open("objFile.txt")]
    objList = [myObj(x) for x in lines]
    return objList
```

I want my Django REST project to call that getObjList function when I try to access the associated URL in a browser (or call via curl or somethig), build a model based on the object it gets back, create a list of that model, serialize it and give it back to me so I can view it in the browsable web interface. Is this possible or am I being an idiot?

Thanks, I've been a C# developer for a bit now but now working in Python and with this HTTP stuff is a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares I figured it out, I had to skip models entirely and just build the serializer directly based on the object I got back, and I had to revert to using more basic django views.

Here is the view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def ObjView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        objList = myObj.getObjList()
        dynamic_serializer = SerializerFactory.first_level(objList)
        return Response(dynamic_serializer.data)
```

the getObjList function is the one posted in my question, but this should work with any function and any object that gets returned, here is what goes on in the serializer factory:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


def first_level(cur_obj):
    isList = False
    ser_val = cur_obj
    if type(cur_obj) in {list, tuple}:
        isList = True
        ser_val = cur_obj[0]

    dynamic_serializer = create_serializer(ser_val)
    return dynamic_serializer(cur_obj, many=isList)


def create_serializer(cur_obj):
    if type(cur_obj) in {list, tuple}:
    if hasattr(cur_obj[0], "__dict__"):
        cur_ser = create_serializer(cur_obj[0])
        return cur_ser(many=True)
    else:
        return serializers.ListField(child=create_serializer(cur_obj[0]))
    elif type(cur_obj) == dict:
        if hasattr(cur_obj.values()[0], "__dict__"):
            child_ser = create_serializer(cur_obj.values()[0])
            return serializers.DictField(child=child_ser())
        else:
            return serializers.DictField(child=create_serializer(cur_obj.values()[0]))
    elif hasattr(cur_obj, "__dict__"):
        attrs = {}
        for key, val in cur_obj.__dict__.items():
            if "__" not in key:
                cur_field = create_serializer(val)
                if hasattr(val, "__dict__"):
                    attrs.update({key: cur_field()})
                else:
                    attrs.update({key: cur_field})
        return type(cur_obj.__name__ + "Serializer", (serializers.Serializer,), attrs)
    else:
        return serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=200)
```

as you can see i had to break it into 2 pieces (I'm sure there's a way to make it one but it wasn't worth it to me to spend time on it) and it involved a substantial amount of recursion and just generally playing with the different field types, this should be good for serializing any combination of objects, lists, dictionaries and simple data types. I've tested it on a pretty wide array of objects and it seems pretty solid.